# Cost Constant in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-5.7

I'm new to MySQL, When I learnt about MySQL 5.7 optimizer it highlighted the term cost model and cost constant. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cost-model.html

I have a question Q. what basis cost constant value were selected?

Example:

```
Cost Operation

40      disk_temptable_create_cost
1       disk_temptable_row_cost
2       memory_temptable_create_cost
0.2     memory_temptable_row_cost
0.1     key_compare_cost
0.2     row_evaluate_cost
1       io_block_read_cost
1       memory_block_read_cost
```